# Linq query and casting in c#

Tags: c#, linq, casting, predicate

I have a class called `BaseViewModel`, and multiple classes inheriting from it.

I have a `List<BaseViewModel>` that contains all the child classes, and not a single `BaseViewModel`.

Now, I would like to extract all of the classes of a specific type, say, my `DateViewModel`, from the `List<BaseViewModel>`

Right now I'm doing this, which throws an `InvalidCastException` :

`CustomFieldViewModels` is my `List<BaseViewModel>` which has a `ControlType` enum that I use to recognize all "childs".

```
public List<DateViewModel> DateCustomViewModels
{
    get
    {
        return (List<DateViewModel>)CustomFieldViewModels
            .Where(x => x.ControlType == CustomFieldControlValueType.Date);
    }
}
```

I'm fairly unfamiliar with Linq and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I'm also pretty sure that doing a `foreach` and fill a `List<DateViewModel>` is not as good performance-wise and isn't very clean.

From what I understand, the `.Where` will return a `List` of whatever I asked, with a filter (here, my enum). I don't understand why there is trouble casting since all my childs inherit from the parent class, and I'm not using a child-specific element in my filtering. Also, even if the type of the main list is of Base, none of its elements are of the Base type, so there shouldn't be any casting to do in the first place.

I feel like I'm missing something terribly obvious but I can't see it, any help is most welcome.

If you provide an answer, it would be very appreciated if you could give a small explanation and not just copy-paste code :)

Edit : For the sake of showing what I ended up doing, I chose a mix of various answers, because I don't need a List, but I still need the type.

```
public IEnumerable<DateControlViewModel> DateCustomViewModels
{
    get
    {
        return CustomFieldControlViewModels.OfType<DateControlViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Where` doesn't return a `List` to start with... you need to call `ToList()` to create a `List<T>` from a query. *Then* you'll end up with the problem of base VM vs specific VM. Does your `CustomFieldViewModels` actually return objects of the right type, properly populated?

Comment: Yes, they are populated and have the right type

Comment: I'm also curious of what you think of Ivan's answer too, compared to Haim's answer.

Comment: Well haim770's answer seems appropriate, but I'd change the return type to `IEnumerable<DateViewModel>`, remove the `ToList()` call, and possibly make it a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `OfType()`:

```
public List<DateViewModel> DateCustomViewModels
{
    get
    {
        return CustomFieldViewModels.OfType<DateViewModel>().ToList()
    }
}
```

> From what I understand, the .Where will return a List of whatever I
>   asked, with a filter (here, my enum)

No, it will return `IEnumerable<BaseViewModel>`. The criteria you specify in the `Where()` doesn't change the return type, it only specifies which of the `BaseViewModel` objects will be included.

> I don't understand why there is trouble casting since all my childs
>   inherit from the parent class, and I'm not using a child-specific
>   element in my filtering.

Even though `DateViewModel` inherits from `BaseViewModel`, you cannot explicitly cast from `List<DateViewModel>` to `List<BaseViewModel>` because `List<T>` is [invariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

> Also, even if the type of the main list is of Base, none of its
>   elements are of the Base type, so there shouldn't be any casting to do
>   in the first place.

You're right, there's no casting needed. Use `OfType<DateViewModel>()` that will only return the objects that are `DateViewModel`. Also, the returned set is now `IEnumerable<DateViewModel>` (it's no longer `List<BaseViewModel>`) and the compiler can verify that it's compatible with the returned type of the `DateCustomViewModels` property.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your answer ! It's much more clearer now :) I'm glad you took the time to respond.

Comment: Also, i'd be glad to know what you think about Ivan's answer, which raises an interesting point.

Comment: @Zil, If you don't specifically need a `List` (just something to represent "many of something"), you definitely better go with `IEnumerable` (that is also co-variant). The reason I ignored it is because your objects are already seem to be in-memory (judged by the name: "ViewModel") and are less affected than `IQueryable` (for example).

Comment: I've created that property for the sole purpose of Validating them with FluentValidator, when the user "submits" whatever he is doing.
The list of Base is what I use to display the right forms for the user, but when validating I need the type-specific validation. So i'll only call it ONCE (on validating), and I'll be honest, I'm not sure I need a list, since the Validator seems to work fine when using an IEnumerable

Comment: @Zil Just to note, the main problem for me is that the `List<T>` is a mutable class. It doesn't matter if the filtering is performed on a in-memory collection or database query. You should return enumerable, because that's what you can produce w/o side effects, and the caller can always call `ToList()`, `ToArray()` or `ToWhatever()` - then he'll know he cannot modify it because it is a snapshot.

Comment: That's very clear and I agree with all your statements :) Thank you very much. I wish I could accept both your answers

Answer (score 1):

From other answers it should be clear now that there is no way to cast the query result to `List<DateViewModel>`. What might not be clear is that the solutions involve creating a new list. Having a **property** of type list that creates a new list anytime called is a **terrible** idea. Consider the following cases

```
// user of your class
yourClass.DateCustomViewModels.Add(new DateViewModel()); // goes nowhere
yourClass.DateCustomViewModels.RemoveAt(0); // removes nothing
// or trying to be smart
for (int i = 0; i < yourClass.DateCustomViewModels.Cout; i++
{
    var model = yourClass.DateCustomViewModels[i];
}
// etc.
```

What you should really do is to change your property signature

```
public IEnumerable<DateViewModel> DateCustomViewModels
{
    get
    {
        // use some of the suggestions in other answers
        // with ToList call removed
    }
}
```